# UIActivityViewController not showing facebook and twitter in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I need to share two things:
1. Audio file
2. Image file

I am passing local paths as items to the `UIActivityViewController`. Previously on **iOS 7** it was showing all required options like **SMS, Mail, Facebook, Twitter**. If I choose **SMS or Email** it attaches photo and audio both. If I choose **Facebook or Twitter** it shares photo only that is fine to me.

Now on **iOS 8** it just shows **SMS and Email**. Why here it is not showing **Facebook and Twitter** like **iOS7**?

Comment: just login on facebook and twitter and then try again, if ur are not login with native facebook and twitter it will not display icon.

Comment: I know this. I am already logged in.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug... Try load it with `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file]` and pass that in instead of the file itself?

Comment: Where you check this ?

Comment: @shukpal : have you get any solution for this? This happening only in iPod, in iPhone it works correct.